# BigQuery Left Join duplicates all rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query, where I have info on some companies over several years, and I want to add the names of the companies from another table. In the output, I get all rows duplicated (exactly twice as many rows as if I just used `select * from main`)

```
select main.*, tickers.name
from  main
left join tickers
on main.ticker = tickers.ticker
order by ticker asc, calendardate desc
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is expected.  Perhaps you should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per `main`, then perhaps you want to concatenate the tickers together:

```
select m.*,
       (select array_agg(t.name)
        from tickers t
        where t.ticker = m.ticker
       ) as ticker_names
from main m
order by ticker asc, calendardate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value(m).*, array_agg(t.name) names
from  main m
left join tickers t
on m.ticker = t.ticker
group by to_json_string(m)
order by ticker asc, calendardate desc
```